# How to pass response variable in path through examples table in karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to pass a variable value in URL path which is further stored in examples table.
Unfortunately, it gives me error.
Can any one please help.

> Background:
>   * def challengeID = res.challengeID
>   * def version = '2'
>   Given url dispatch    And path  `'/api/fire/v' + version + '/sms/otp/' + <challengeID>`
>   And param code = `<code>`
>   And header Content-Type = `'application/json'`
>   When method GET Then status 400

```
Examples:   
| challengeID    | code    |   
| #(challengeID) | 2121211 |   
| 3434343434343  | 111111  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the `Examples:` table *cannot* be dynamic. This is standard "Cucumber" behavior. Use `table` instead: https://github.com/intuit/karate#table

But I think you are over-complicating things. You should just do this:

```
And path 'api/fire/v' + version + '/sms/otp', res.challengeID
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter. That means I have to create two scenarios.